# how to obtain output without [] in python and how do i get an output without [none]

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
def group_list(group, users):
  members = [ print('{}:{}'.format(group,users) )]
  return members

print(group_list("Marketing", ["Mike", "Karen", "Jake", "Tasha"]))
```

Output: Marketing:['Mike', 'Karen', 'Jake', 'Tasha']
[None]

Desired output : Marketing: Mike, Karen, Jake, Tasha

Comment: `print()` returns None ... why create a list of `[None]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to make a single string out of the `users` list, without surrounding`[]`.

and then your original format to add the `Marketing:` prefix, like this:

```py
def group_list(group, users):
  members = '{}: {}'.format(group,', '.join(users))
  return members

print(group_list("Marketing", ["Mike", "Karen", "Jake", "Tasha"]))
```

Output:
`Marketing: Mike, Karen, Jake, Tasha`

The reason you got `[None]` is this is the return value from `print`, which you saved inside a list.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert list to string using this function. And call list to string function inside your group list function where you're formatting to joining them.

```
def listToString(s):
    # initialize an empty string 
    str1 = ", "
    return (str1.join(s))

def group_list(group, users):
    members = '{}: {}'.format(group,listToString(users))
    return members

print(group_list("Marketing", ["Mike", "Karen", "Jake", "Tasha"]))
```